# Intermittently Selenium WebDriver click does not reflect changes in UI

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In order to click an element, we wait for an element to be clickable using explicit wait and then click on the element. After clicking on element, it does not result into an error. This indicates click has succeed.

Hence after click, some changes are expected in UI. Suppose, appearance of some button. We again use explicit wait, of suppose 30 seconds, for the button to appear but that button never appears.(In screenshot after failure also, we could not see that button). This happens only when we run using Selenium, manually it works perfectly fine.

What could be the possible reasons for this and what is better way to handle this intermittent issue?

Comment: If you could add some code or the link to the site that you are testing.

Comment: do you have frontend designed in angular js or react js? if yes then try to click with javascript.

Comment: @Muzamil, it's using jQuery